# Derivative of matrix product

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I keep messing up my indices and not getting the right answer.  I want to compute

$$
\dfrac{d}{dJ_i}
\dfrac{d}{dJ_j}\exp\left(  \dfrac{1}{2}\mathbb{J}\cdot\mathbb{A}^{-1} \cdot\mathbb{J}  \right)=~?
$$

For this notation $\mathbb{J}$ can be written $J_\lambda$ and $\mathbb{A}^{-1}$ (which is symmetric) can be written $A^{-1}_{\lambda\rho}$.  We have necessarily

$$
\dfrac{d}{dJ_i}\left(\mathbb{J}\cdot x\right)=\dfrac{d}{dJ_i}\sum J_\lambda x_\lambda=x_i
$$

Therefore, I want to rewite the main equation which is giving me problems as

$$
\dfrac{d}{dJ_i}
\dfrac{d}{dJ_j}\exp\left(  \dfrac{1}{2}\sum\sum J_\lambda A^{-1}_{\lambda\rho}J_\rho  \right)=~?
$$

However, when I start to doing the chain rule I end up with too many terms that don't seem to cancel.  I guess, the simplest way to ask my question is if I am doing this derivative correctly.

$$
\dfrac{d}{dJ_j}\left(  \dfrac{1}{2}\sum\sum J_\lambda A^{-1}_{\lambda\rho}J_\rho  \right)=\dfrac{1}{2} \left( \sum  A^{-1}_{j\rho}J_\rho + \sum J_\lambda A^{-1}_{\lambda j} \right)=\sum  A^{-1}_{j\rho}J_\rho 
$$

Is that right ($A^{-1}$ is symmetric)?  My thinking, which seems to be wrong because if I stopped thinking it then I would get the right answer right away, is that $d/dJ_\alpha$ needs to take the derivative like

$$
\dfrac{d}{dJ_i}
\dfrac{d}{dJ_j}\exp\left(  \dfrac{1}{2}\sum\sum J_\lambda A^{-1}_{\lambda\rho}J_\rho  \right)=$$

\begin{align}
&=\dfrac{d}{dJ_i}
\exp\left(  \dfrac{1}{2}\sum\sum J_\lambda A^{-1}_{\lambda\rho}J_\rho  \right)\dfrac{d}{dJ_j}\left(  \dfrac{1}{2}\sum\sum J_\lambda A^{-1}_{\lambda\rho}J_\rho  \right)\\
&=\dfrac{d}{dJ_i}
\exp\left(  \dfrac{1}{2}\sum\sum J_\lambda A^{-1}_{\lambda\rho}J_\rho  \right) \sum  A^{-1}_{j\rho}J_\rho\\
&=\exp\left(  \dfrac{1}{2}\sum\sum J_\lambda A^{-1}_{\lambda\rho}J_\rho  \right)\dfrac{d}{dJ_i}\left(  \dfrac{1}{2}\sum\sum J_\lambda A^{-1}_{\lambda\rho}J_\rho  \right)\left( \sum  A^{-1}_{j\rho}J_\rho  \right)+\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad+
\exp\left(  \dfrac{1}{2}\sum\sum J_\lambda A^{-1}_{\lambda\rho}J_\rho  \right)\dfrac{d}{dJ_i}\left( \sum  A^{-1}_{j\rho}J_\rho  \right)\\
&=
\exp\left(  \dfrac{1}{2}\sum\sum J_\lambda A^{-1}_{\lambda\rho}J_\rho  \right)\left(  \sum  A^{-1}_{i\rho}J_\rho  \right)\left( \sum  A^{-1}_{j\rho}J_\rho  \right)+
\exp\left(  \dfrac{1}{2}\sum\sum J_\lambda A^{-1}_{\lambda\rho}J_\rho  \right)\left(   A^{-1}_{ji} \right)
\end{align}

...etc.  I think I have already gotten an error by the time I have this many terms.  The answer say the derivative should bring down $A^{-1}_{ij}$ which is my second term, but I have this first term too which, I guess, should disappear when I don't do it wrong.  Would some kind person please point out my error or take this derivative for me step by step?  Thanks :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to obtain the expected result, I was supposed to set J=0 at the end, so I do get the right answer (i think.)  oops.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the convention where uppercase Latin represent matrices, lowercase Latin vectors, and Greeks are scalars.

Then let's use symbols which are easier to type
$$\eqalign{
 B &= B^T=A^{-1} \cr
 x &= {\mathbb J} \cr
 \mu &= \tfrac{1}{2}x^TBx &\implies d\mu = (Bx)^Tdx \cr
 \alpha &= \exp(\mu) &\implies d\alpha = \alpha\,d\mu \cr
}$$
Let's continue the expansion of $d\alpha$ and find its gradient
$$\eqalign{
d\alpha &= \alpha(Bx)^Tdx \cr
g &= \frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial x} = \alpha Bx \cr
}$$
Now find the differential and gradient of $g$
$$\eqalign{
dg &= Bx\,d\alpha + \alpha B\,dx \cr
 &= Bx\,\alpha(Bx)^Tdx + \alpha B\,dx \cr
 &= \alpha Bxx^TB\,dx + \alpha B\,dx \cr
H &= \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \alpha(B+Bxx^TB) \cr
}$$
Finally, setting $\,x=0\,$ yields $\,\alpha = e^0=1\,$ and $\,H = B$.